# How prevalent are midges in Beara Peninsula

Tags: ireland, insects

I am very interested in travelling to Beara Peninsula and surrounding mountain ranges.

My research suggests there may be some midges in the area, will the midge outbreaks be similar in quantity and ferocity to the Scottish Highlands and Western Isles? Or is it less of an issue in and around Beara?

Thanks for your help.